# List contains another list and based on logic main list should modify

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of objects like below. The resulting list should not contain recipes if any ingredient past useBy date. Is this possible to achieve with Java Streams.

I was trying to do it like below but getting a compiling error. Really appreciate a response since I am struggling a lot to find an answer.

```
List<Recipes> filteredList =
    recipeList.stream().filter(recipes -> recipes.getIngredients().stream().filter(ingredients -> ingredients.getUseBy().before(lunchDate)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "recipeName": "Pasta",
            "createdDate": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000+00:00",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredientId": 1,
                    "ingredientName": "Shells",
                    "useBy": "2020-11-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-11-18"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": 2,
                    "ingredientName": "Mozaralla Cheese",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-11-23"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "recipeName": "Burger",
            "createdDate": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000+00:00",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredientId": 3,
                    "ingredientName": "Burger Bun",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": 4,
                    "ingredientName": "Beef Pattie",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": 5,
                    "ingredientName": "Tomato",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "recipeName": "Chicken Salad",
            "createdDate": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000+00:00",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredientId": 6,
                    "ingredientName": "Salad Mix",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-11-15"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": 7,
                    "ingredientName": "Chicken",
                    "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                    "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting? Also, how are you storing (what I'm assuming is `JSON`) inside `recipeList`?

Comment: Error is Required type Boolean - Provided List <Recipes>. 
`Ingredients` are the list for each Recipe use to made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example (not using JSON) [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_java/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64961341).

Consider the following:

```
List<Recipe> filteredList = 
    recipes.stream()
           .filter(r -> ! r.getIngredients()
                           .stream()
                           .anyMatch(i -> i.getUseBy().before(lunchDate)))                         
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A description is, for each recipe:

- get the ingredients
- find any 'bad' ingredients with `useBy` before `lunchDate`
- exclude (via `!` operator) the recipe if there are any 'bad' ingredients

Answer (score 1):

`Stream().filter()` takes a `Predicate<T>` as parameter and returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate. Your requirements can be rephrased as:

```
List<Recipes> filteredList = recipeList.stream().filter(predicate: recipes does not contain any ingredient past useBy date).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

And your problem is changed to write the predicate that matches: recipes does not contain any ingredient past `useBy` date. (For any recipe, count the ingredients pass the `useBy` date, the count should be 0.)

And you can use another `stream().filter(predicate: count ingredient after useBy date, and it should be 0)`

```
recipes -> recipes.getIngredients().stream()
    .filter(ingredients -> ingredients.getUseBy().after(lunchDate))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0
```

Then add the predicate to your first filter expression. The final expression is like this:

```
List<Recipes> filteredList = recipeList.stream().filter(
    recipes -> recipes.getIngredients().stream()
        .filter(ingredients -> ingredients.getUseBy().after(lunchDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0
).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```